# Hibernate Session Factory taking long time to load

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration, sessionfactory

I have created custom session factory provider class. Where I am setting hibernate properties and annotated classes. I have more then 100 annotated classes. While I am login to application it takes long time to load session factory. Is there any way to overcome this issue or I am doing any mistake? Please help me.

```
public class SessionFatoryProvider {

    public void setNewSessionFactory(String uname,String password,HttpSession hs){

        String jdbcUrl = Constants.DB_URL+Constants.DB;
        java.util.Properties hibernateProperties = new java.util.Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driverClassNames", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", jdbcUrl);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", uname);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","none");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("current_session_context_class","org.hibernate.context.spi.AbstractCurrentSessionContext");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache","false");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache","false");

        LocalSessionFactoryBean slfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        slfb.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        slfb.setPackagesToScan("com.orb.bean"); //My entity class package

        try {
            slfb.afterPropertiesSet();
         } catch (Exception e) {                      
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

        SessionFactory mySessionFactory = slfb.getObject();
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(mySessionFactory);

        hs.setAttribute("HibernateTransactionManager", transactionManager); //Here I am setting hibernate transaction manager in session

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already use Spring (e.g. [LocalSessionFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html)), you should [configure the application context](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring) so that the LocalSessionFactoryBean is a singleton.

So there's no need to create the SessionFactory manually. This applies to the transaction management configuration as well.

According to the [reference documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html), the SessionFactory is an expensive object and since it's a thread-safe object, it should be a singleton instead:

> A SessionFactory is an expensive-to-create, threadsafe object,
>   intended to be shared by all application threads. It is created once,
>   usually on application startup, from a Configuration instance.

Comment: What If I want to login to application using system database user keeping single session factory and different connection?

Comment: So what holds you back? You can have one session factory and multiple connections.

Comment: Yes I know that,but how can I create single session factory while I am having system database users for login to application not application user.

Comment: You need a SessionFactory to the database schema you want to connect to. If your system users are not mapped to entities, you can use a native query then.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to create a Session Factory per user. Set up a system database user that is used by the application to connect to the database.
Your application should contain only one session factory.

Initialize your session factory during start-up of the application. If it is a web application you can do this with a start-up servlet.

Comment: That is ok, but I need to login to application through system database user and maintain different connection per user.

Comment: We ran into a similar issue with an application that insisted on using database users. We ended up having to use standard JDBC. We built our own connection pool to handle the different connections. This, of course, makes the connection pool very inefficient, since you now have one or more connections per user instead of sharing a pool of connections.